# Show $G$ is isomorphic to $X \times Y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

How do you prove this isomorphism?

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H = X \times Y,\;\;\;  X , Y\leq G$. Prove that $G\simeq H$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: This is very false in general. Is the question asking about specific groups?

Answer (score 1):

$X=Y=\{e\}$ with $G \neq \{e\}$ comes to mind as a counterexample. I'm not sure what hypothesis you are missing.

Comment: I think OP is probably looking for some criterion such as $HK=G$ $H, K\unlhd G$ and $H\cap K=(e)$.

Comment: @MartinRattigan If these are the criterion that i missed how could i prove it?

Comment: There is an obvious map from the external direct product of $H$ and $K$ into $g$ given by $(h,k)\mapsto hk$. Show that under the given criteria it's an isomporphism onto $G$.